# Not JSON Serializable Django Session

Tags: python, django

In my django view, I have the below:

`manifestData = form2.cleaned_data`

`form2` is a formset which will have a dynamic number of forms within it.  So in one instance it may have just one form, but in a different case it might have 3 or 5, etc, etc.  For example, if it contains 2 forms and I execute `print(manifestData)` I will get the output:

`[{'ProductCode': <Product: APPLES-1>, 'UnitQty': u'11', 'Price': u'11.00', 'Amount': u'121', 'DescriptionOfGoods': u'Washington Extra Fancy', 'Type': u'Cases', u'id': None, u'DELETE': False}, {'ProductCode': <Product: ORANGES-1>, 'UnitQty': u'1', 'Price': u'12.00', 'Amount': u'12', 'DescriptionOfGoods': u'SUNKIST ORANGES', 'Type': u'Cases', u'id': None, u'DELETE': False}]`

Next, in my view I am trying to pass that `manifestData` to another view via the session like so:

```
def quoteView(request):
...
request.session['manifestData'] = x
return redirect('QuotePreview')


class QuotePreview(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        manifestData = request.session.pop('x', {})
...
```

However I get an error on this line `request.session['manifestData'] = x` which mentions "APPLES-1 is not JSON Serializable".  I believe this is because this is a foreignkey reference to a product model.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ProductCode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    HSCode = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    DescriptionOfGoods = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    UnitType = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ProductCode)
```

Question is primarily - how can I make these product codes JSON serializable so that they may be used in the session? Thanks!d

Comment: What data are you trying to serializer as JSON? `manifestData`? What is the type of `manifestData` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu ```manifestData``` - I suppose that when I do ```request.session['manifestData'] = x``` that it is attempting to serialize the data.